# Construction of the matrix of a linear map between two vector spaces : difficulty in understanding how an expression represents a coordinate vector.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Source : Prof. Bachman, Nagoya University :  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=omn5827Wd5o&list=PLEaZuUNvNSmh_5lNwCR5wfbp5ue4Ho7rM&index=4 ,  at time $6:22$

In a YT video made for a Linear Algebra II course , Professor Bachman shows how to construct the matrix of a linear map $F$ from a vector space $V$ with bassis $Bv= \{v_1, ... , v_n \}$ to a vector space $W$ with basis $Bw = \{w_1,  ... w_m\}$ .

[image]

His strategy is to construct the desired matrix as the matrix of the composed function from $R^n$ to $R^m$, namely  of the function $C^{-1}_{Bw} \circ  F \circ C_{Bv}$ ,

where

- $C_{Bv} $ is the coordinate map that assigns to every n-tuple ( column vector)  in  $R^n$ , $\{\lambda_1 , ... \lambda_n\}$ the vector of $V$ defined by : $\lambda_1 v_1 + ... \lambda_n v_n$.
- $C_{Bw}$ is the equivalent coordinate map from $R^m$ to $W$
- $C^{-1}_{Bw}$ is the inverse of the previous one, namely, the map that assigns to every element of $W$ its coordinate ( column) vector in $R^m$.

Note : after that, he will determine what this function does to the canonic basis of $R^n$ , since, as a general rule, the matrix of a linear map has, as columns, the image of the elements of the canonic basis.

Note : my question does not deal with the drawing representing  the composed function.

> My question deals with the fourth element of  first line written by
> Prof. Bachman in the screenshot above, after the third arrow  . This
> line aims at showing how works the composed function $C^{-1}_{Bw}
>  \circ  F \circ C_{Bv}$

I understand how an element of $R^n$ is sent to $V$ by $C_{Bv}$ and how  this image is, in turn , sent to $W$ by $F$ ( using the fact that $F$ is a linear map).

What I do not get is the way the last element ( belonging to $R^m$) is written.

This element should be a column vector, for $C^{-1}_{Bw}$ gives as output cordinate ( column ) vectors in $R^m$.

The fourth expression contains a (column) coordinate  vector in it , namely $[F(v_i)]_{Bw}$, but I fail to see how the entire sigma expression represents a column coordinate vector.

Answer (score 1):

If you accept that the $[F(v_i)]_{B_W}$ are column vectors (one for every i from $1$ to $n$) then the sigma expression is just a sum of scaled column vectors, i.e. a column vector.